# Add OTF font Latin Modern Roman in ghostscript for vectorized pdf generation

Tags: matlab, fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript, eps

I would like to add the Latin Modern Roman 12 (LM Roman 12) OTF font in Ghostscript (Windows10, 64bit, v.9.22) to export Matlab figures in vectorized pdf/eps format.

I have two solutions to export the Matlab figures in pdf/eps : using Matlab interface (File -> save as...) or directly calling Ghostscript with this [Matlab function](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). However, when I try to export a figure with LM Roman 12 in eps/pdf using both alternatives, LM Roman 12 is swapped with Courier font. I suppose that both alternatives are in fact using Ghostscript.

I have naturally installed the font package in the windows' font panel setup so I can access it from Matlab. However, I have seen that the new font must also be installed in the Ghostscript's font_map. The [official font documentation of Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Fonts.htm) says that the new font should be added in Font_map.gs. When I look for the font_map file in my Ghostscript directory, I find severy font_map with different extensions :

[image: Screenshot of the font_maps list]

I wonder then which one to modify and if there is a simpler solution to set new font in Ghoscript.

Thanks for your help,

Emile

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'it depends' :-)

On Windows the fonts are built into the executable, along with their font map. So you can't readily alter that.

You can find better documentation on adding fonts, rather on than on font formats [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Use.htm#Font_lookup) There are multiple ways to achieve what you seem to be doing, but the simplest, probably is to put the fonts you want in a convenient directory somewhere, and add that directory to the Ghostscript search path with the -I switch. You can also modify the GS_FONTPATH environment variable and add the path there, that woks on Windows too.

Then in that folder create a file called Fontmap.GS (**NOTE** not Font_map.GS as you have in your question), and in that put the reference to the font you want to add.

That should add the folder to the search list, then GS should read the Fontmap.GS file and add the font to its list of known fonts at startup.

You should check the outline format of the OTF font, I'm not certain whether an OTF with CFF outlines will work as expected.